# Pechkin converting webpage to pdf c# gives empty pdf.

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I am exploring Pechkin to convert webpage to PDF. I have used article: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/366/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-html-using-wkhtmltopdf-with-c-in-winforms

Ref: [How to use wkhtmltopdf.exe in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791981/how-to-use-wkhtmltopdf-exe-in-asp-net)

When i try to convert using html string, it works !

```
byte[] pdfContent = new SimplePechkin(new GlobalConfig()).Convert("<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>");
```

However when I follow "Generate PDF from a Website" section, I get empty pdf.

```
configuration.SetCreateExternalLinks(false)
    .SetFallbackEncoding(Encoding.ASCII)
    .SetLoadImages(true)
    .SetPageUri("http://ourcodeworld.com");
```

Has anyone encountered same issue? Appreciate all help/suggestions.

Comment: did you ever got any solution for this?? I observed that it works with certain sites and not all. Couple of sites that worked for me were news website http://thehindu.com and my blog on blogspot http://technicalsmile.blogspot.com

Comment: I ended up using http://phantomjs.org/ to convert webpage to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin

```
var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
{
    GlobalSettings =
    {
        ProduceOutline = true,
        DocumentTitle = "Pretty Websites",
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4, // Implicit conversion to PechkinPaperSize
        Margins =
        {
            All = 1.375,
            Unit = Unit.Centimeters
        }
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = "<h1>Pretty Websites</h1><p>This might take a bit to convert!</p>" },
        new ObjectSettings { PageUrl = "www.google.com" },
        new ObjectSettings { PageUrl = "www.microsoft.com" },
        new ObjectSettings { PageUrl = "www.github.com" }
    }
};
 var tempFolderDeployment = new TempFolderDeployment();
 var win32EmbeddedDeployment = new Win32EmbeddedDeployment(tempFolderDeployment);
 var remotingToolset = new RemotingToolset<PdfToolset>(win32EmbeddedDeployment);

 var converter = ThreadSafeConverter(remotingToolset);
 byte[] pdfBuf = converter.Convert(document);
 // Very important - overwise cpu will grow !!!
 remotingToolset.Unload();
```

---

### Edit

---

If someone else use this- please read my post here- **very important**!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62428122/4836581

If you get errors use this link that help me-

[TuesPechkin unable to load DLL 'wkhtmltox.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882601/tuespechkin-unable-to-load-dll-wkhtmltox-dll)

Found it thanks to-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993484/4836581

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using different library. I appreciate your response.